# RESTserver POST request format

Tags: codeigniter, rest

I am developing an API using CodeIgniter and the RestServer for CI (see below). I am also using the Firefox RestClient plugin to test the API.

What I am wondering is how to do the test post (what format).

Tried {"desc":"value"} but it did not work. The API is not "seeing" the incoming post fields.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Comment: Honestly just use cURL to make sure it's handling the requests fine, if you verify that, this is more of a "how to use this software" question, than a programming question.

Comment: I am going to use this API inside an iOS app build with Appcelerator. Right now I build my API with Ruby but I am testing PHP. When using the Ruby API I could sen JSON objects but not now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the post body doesn't need to have a specific format, but the most convenient is to encode the body in the same way web browsers encode form data, specifically `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  In particular, the `Host` and `Content-Length` headers are *not* optional, and the `Content-Type` header is usually needed to tell the server how to interpret the body. A well formed POST request will look like:

```
POST /path/to/resource HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com:80
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

key=value&key2=value2
```

It's still up to the server to recognize the content-type header and parse the body that way.

Note that the data is after all the headers, not as part of the request path (in the first line).

Comment: This works great! What would I do to send the same data in JSON-format?

Comment: json has a content type of `application/json` (among a few others, but use that one), and just include the json encoded data in the post body as normal.  That said, it's rarely necessary to use request content types other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Why do you think you need to?

Comment: @Jonathan: If you have a question about generating json data for a particular client platform, I advise you ask another question.  Comments should be used to elaborate on the specifics of the question or answer they're attached to.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, you can use [Proxy Library](https://github.com/toopay/CI-Proxy-Library) which i wrote for CI. With that, you can simulate any of possible call to your API(its works for popular REST API too), with more simple syntax instead using cURL...

```
// An example call to your API end point using POST, will be simply
$this->load->library('proxy');
$this->proxy->http('POST', 'http://somesite.com/api/users', array('username' => 'foo', 'password' => 'bar'));
```

You can define whatsoever HTTP header too (like API Key or whatever else).